# Creating database through code first EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget

I have the following code for my `Cliente` class

```
public class Cliente
{
    public Cliente()
    {
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string sobrenome {get;set;}
}
```

`Login` class :

```
public class Login
{
    public Login()
    {
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string login { get; set; }
    public string senha { get; set; }
}
```

`Context` class:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(): base("name=Context")
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString =@"data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=BancoTeste; Integrated Security=SSPI";
    }
    public DbSet<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Login> Login { get; set; }
}
```

I'm kinda new to programming, found some examples on the internet and tried to do the same

This code ain't suppose to create a database ?

Comment: Did you try to run the project and do any database activities? Got any messages?

Comment: Yes, the project runs with no problems, but the db isn't there :/. No messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a Database Initializer set, like @Michael described, then EF will only create your database once you attempt to access it. So for example if you add the following to one of your controllers, EF will create it:

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    var allClients = context.Cliente.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start the application, you need to run this line:

```
Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context>());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way using Package Manager.

Note: You may need to install Nuget Package Manager using Visual Studio Extension Manager

Locate your Package Manager Console and then run following commands

```
//(Get the latest version of Entity Framework for you (May not need if you have it))
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework 

// (This will enable database migrations from your model to database)
PM> Enable-Migrations

//(Create a database migration in SolutionExplorer\Migration folder for you)
PM> Add-Migration GiveItAProperName 

//(This will commit those changes to the database or create the database)
PM> Update-Database 

//In the future, if you change your model, do the following to update the database
PM> Add-Migration MyFirstChangesToTheDatabase
PM> Update-Database
```

You can add more parameters to above PM commands, please use `get-help commandName` for more information

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use Entity Migration.

You can use commands in package manager console to create new migrations and update your database with your updated model.

[Example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

With this solution, you can generate code to upgrade and downgrade your database.